# How to use Anthos for home or personal compute resources?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-anthos

At no-cost for personal-developer use, for using only local compute resources.

Cloud-agnostication is exiting tech!  Thanks Sundar/google! I recall the days where phone-numbers could not be ported.  Perhaps should become an evangelist :).

**My constraints:**

1. I'm an individual developer who is exited about cloud-agnostic
   aspect that google is introducing.
2. I do not want to go through the dreaded "purchase approval" pyramid while experimenting. Also for self learning, it would be easier if it comes at no cost.
3. I have 2 laptops at home, perhaps 4-6 cores total compute power.

**My requirement:**

Without additional cost, would Anthos allow me (just a developer) to use my local compute power e.g 2laptops x 2cores, create/deploy *cloud-ready* applications, and test the cloud-readiness by deploying using Anthos-AMP in local home network. Once those are working, I can deploy in my personal GCP account.

Answer (score 1):

Given that Google Anthos was just announced this month at Google Next '19, details will change over time.

Running Google Anthos (today) on-premises requires VMware vCenter 6.5. This means using your laptop for local compute power is not supported. [What's required to run Anthos?](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/)

Google Anthos is not free. Currently a 1-year subscription starts at $10,000 per month. [Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/pricing)